# Edit css files from django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

My client wants to edit the css files of the site from django admin.
Is there any way to do it ? .
Basically what they want is,to be able to change the color,font etc of the data in the front end from django admin interface.

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do it - more than one FWIW. Now what have _you_ tried ?

Comment: I googled for apps that does the job.found none.please help he with this...

Comment: well you could uh... create a model called Style and use it to create a manageable css template that would be used on a different views, though that's sounds like a lot of work for something that should be a lot more flexible. Wouldn't it be easier to create a view to edit the css code on the web (and limit it to admin-users). There are great client-side packages for this ([here's one](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about))

Answer (score 3):

The best thing would be to just let him edit the css file itself. CSS is, in essence, a rather flexible tool, so writing a way to manage it is rather tough (and really, overkill). It's *already* easy to pick-up, and any nice editor like [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) would probably be easier and more natural than whatever you'll build using the admin site. Also, by building a simple way to control css, your client will probably start asking for more and more flexibility until you find yourself building an entire cms (trust me, I've been there myself).

What's more, your client probably only wants to manage small aspects or details of the site. Recently I had a project where I allowed my users to style their display of my application. The way I did it was to create a UserDesign model which extended the base User model and kept very specific css data. Something like this:

```
class UserDesign(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    background_color = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    font_color = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=COLORS)
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=THEMES)
```

Meaning, they didn't control the entirety of the css, but they did get to choose the background color and some other information. It's a very neat addition to any website. However, if you are bent over doing it the hard way, I'd do something like this:

```
class Selector(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def get_template(self):
        attrs = [a.join() for a in self.attr_set.all()]
        return """ %s { %s } """ % ( self.name, ';'.join(attrs) )


class Attr(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    selector = models.ForeignKey(Selector)

    def join(self):
        return ': '.join(self.key, self.value)
```

I chose 30 as the max_length completely arbitrarily (you might need it longer), and you can use a TabularInline to make each selector easy to manage. Then you can easily use different css definitions inside your templates themselves:

```
<style>
{% for selector in selectors %}
    {{ selector.get_template }}
{% endfor %}
</style>
```

Of course, the Selector model would probably need another field called 'template' or 'view' or something, to link it to a certain html file, though at this point it quickly start devolving into building your own cms (which, as mentioned before, is quite a headache that not wanting to edit a text file just doesn't justify)

A third viable option is to create a view with a code-editor, and just let your client edit his css through the web page. There's more than enough client-side plugins out there, like [ace](http://ace.c9.io) or [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) (and of course, limit that view to administrators, which very simple to do).

Comment: thanks that was useful...but first i will try to convince my client not to do it :)